# Android pass value from activity to adapter

Tags: android

I want to pass variable from activity to adapter.

My adapter looks like this

```
  public SampleAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<SampleBeans> data){
  this.context = context;
  this.data = data;
  }
```

My Activity looks like this

```
  newadapter = new SampleAdapter(this);
  newadapter.setId(Login_uuid_value);
```

Gives me error SampleAdapter cannot be applied to the activity.

Comment: send data like this newadapter = new SampleAdapter(this,data);

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply add the values to the constructor.

```
public SimpleAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<SimpleBeans> data, String mystring, int myInt){
  //use datas here
}
```

And use it like

```
myAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, myString, myInt);
```

Obiouvsly you can set all the datas you want, mine were some examples.

In your case you simply need to add the arrayList to the constructor.

```
myAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myArrayList);
```

Answer (score 3):

Declare Your Adapter In Activity

```
private ChatsAdapter chatsAdapter;
```

Initiate Your Adapter in OnCreate in Activity (sendingEntity will be your String which you want to pass)

```
chatsAdapter = new ChatsAdapter(lIndividualChats, sendingEntity);
```

Declare Variable In Adapter

```
private String entity;
```

Catch it in Adapter Constructor

```
public ChatsAdapter(List<ChatModel> individualChats, String sendingEntity) {

    this.individualChats = individualChats;
    entity = sendingEntity;

}
```

Use it anywhere in your adapter

```
Log.d(TAG, "entity: " +entity);
```